# Extending Underscore's functionalities

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

But what happens if you want to add (for the sake of the topic), 50 custom mixins, where only some, actually need to tap into underscore's chaining functionality, and the rest... you just want them under the `_` scope.

```
var mixins = {
    mixin_a: function() { /* do something... */ },
    mixin_b: function() { /* do something else... */ },
    // ...
    mixin_xyz: function() {/* do whatever... */ }
}

_.mixin(mixins);
```

Now, for `mixin_a`, unless its a method which we need to chain with ex: `_.map()`, we can call it either from the underscore scope `_.mixin_a()`, or from its original container, `mixins.mixin_a()` and we get the same output.

It seems wrong to have the "same" functionality in 2 objects that exist in the global scope.

Of course, you can keep your logic separate, and `_.mixin()` only what is absolutely necessary, and keep the rest as plain old functions to call whenever you need them, or create your custom scope etc., but, **what I'm looking for is a way to hardcode the methods in the underscore file itself.**

I could start editing the actual underscore library, but for the sake of sanity, i'll just say i did... and don't.

Maybe a [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) way to do it?

Comment: I removed the noise from the question description, but even after that, it's still not very clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to bundle the underscore.js file with your own file?

Comment: Will that extend the `_` object, without the need to call the mixin method?

Comment: Extending Underscore and bundling are two distinct problems. Please edit your question to clearly state what is your intention and what you are not able to achieve.